# Creating TFS branches one level deeper than Main breaks external dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I'm having an XY-problem, but I have to deal with Y at the moment. The X-problem is that my project and solution file refer to externals outside the Team Project, e.g.:

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\External\Dependency.csproj">
```

I'm trying to create a branch of my Team Project application, and to be tidy I created a `Branches` folder to hold those branches, resulting in this (example) structure:

```
$/MyProject/Main                    << with sln file and a folder per csproj
$/MyProject/Branches/FeatureXYZ     << a branch of "Main"
```

After branching, I opened the `sln` in `Main` and verified things were still building. After that I opened the `sln` from `Branches/FeatureXYZ` using the Team Explorer, but found that the `Dependency` project could not be loaded.

After investigating the folders on disk, it dawned on me that the `sln` and `csproj` are *not* duplicated / branched in the `Branches/FeatureXYZ` branch, but rather *reused* from `Main`. Coming from DVCSes this caught me somewhat by surprise, but it does explain the issue I'm having.

What is the solution (given that I cannot fix the *actual* X problem at this moment)? Is there a proper way or modus where `sln` and `csproj` files are *not* reused?

The only workaround I could think of was to be less tidy and make `FeatureXYZ` a direct sibling of `Main`. Or *is* that the (only feasible) solution to my case?

Comment: How did you map your workspaces?

Comment: @TfsAgent Oh my, that matters? I did not realize my personal workspaces would / could influence the way files come out of TFS. I will investigate and add the missing info to my question.

Comment: When you branch it should be identical copy, but in different folder structure. The workspace mapping is important to get your external reference [as you have one folder level difference, your project reference needs to take care of that ref logic]. And try to start with a clean folder/workspace, not to confuse by old files sitting around...

Answer (score 1):

If you use this `..\..\External\Dependency.csproj` to refer the Dependency project.

Obviously you must make sure your branch \Main  and \FeatureXYZ are the same folder level  to the file \External\Dependency.csproj in your dev machine.

So either make FeatureXYZ a direct sibling of Main as you said, or change the workspace mapping structure as @TfsAgent mentioned. Don't map the *MyProject* directly. Map $/MyProject/Main and $/MyProject/Branches/FeatureXYZ separately.